# Query N last records in reverse order with scope

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I store user messages in db. I need to query last 10 records, and return them in reverse order, so suppose user creates message_1, message_2 and message_3. I want result to be ordered like: `[message_1, message_2, message_3]`, i.e. last message is last in result. But this scope:

```
scope :last_page, -> ()  { order('created_at DESC').limit(10)
```

returns records like `[message_3, message_2, message_1]`, i.e. last message is on top.

What I've tried is:

```
  scope :last_page, -> ()  { order('created_at DESC').limit(10).sort_by(&:created_at) }
```

which produces   desired result, but returns Array, rather than `ActiveRecord::Relation`. I'd love scope to return relation rather than array. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can't use `sort_by` inside the scope. scope is chains and build a SQL for you. `sort_by` is Ruby enumerable method works with your data in memory. You need to apply some other tricks

Comment: exactly right. I'd ask why you're sorting? doesn't the `order('...')` take care of that?

Answer (score 1):

`order('created_at DESC')` will give you the *latest(or last)* as *first* or simply a *descending order*. You need to combine `order('created_at ASC')` with `last`. The below code should work.

```
scope :last_page, -> ()  { order('created_at ASC').last(10)
```

*or*

```
scope :last_page, -> ()  { order('created_at').last(10)
```

Comment: does that return an array of results or the ActiveRecord::Relation? I'm wondering if you can even get the relation from a scope at all. Not sure.

Comment: @jaydel All scope methods will return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object.

Comment: cool, thanks. my next question is, is last() a method on `ActiveRecord::Relation` or on `Array`/`Enumerable`?

Comment: @jaydel There is a ActiveRecord's [*last*](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/last/class) and also there is a [*last*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-last) method which can be used on array.

Comment: This still returns array rather then scope.